# Saving and retrieving with AsyncStorage error

Tags: typescript, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a storage object as follows:

```
import AsyncStorage from "react-native";

const deviceStorage = {
    async saveItem(key, value) {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
        }
      }
};

export default deviceStorage;
```

`setItem` is throwing an error

```
Property 'setItem' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/Developer/React/reactRallyApp/node_modules/@types/react-native/index")'
```

I can't see why this is happening or how to resolve, am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AsyncStorage will be removed from react native core, use this instead: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage
2. You are putting a function in an object without a key.

You could do this:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

const saveItem = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
};

export default saveItem;
```

Comment: this didn't fix the warning and created a new one on the `await`... 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.

Comment: sorry just added the async key word

Comment: oh yeah and you forgot the curly brackets around AsyncStorage now the code should word